# What is the correct way to import a native node module when using flow?

Tags: node.js, flowtype

I have flow set up correctly, and it's working for most of my code (using React with all of the type definitions imported using flow-typed), however I am having trouble getting flow to cover this small file which imports a native node module (`events`):

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

const eventBus: events.EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
export default eventBus;
```

Flow is saying that line 3 `const eventBus...` is not covered by flow, flagging that `new EventEmitter()` is the issue. I thought that by specifying the type `eventBus: events.EventEmitter` that would solve the issue, but that seems to not be the case.

Is there something obviously wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sillyness on my behalf (typically only realised as soon as I asked the question), the issue was nothing to do with flow, but the first import was incorrect. It should be `import EventEmitter from 'events'` and the type would then be `eventBus: EventEmitter`